# RE: Importing awkward dataset to R

Tags: r, csv

I have some csv datasets (so-called DATRAS "exchange data" from [ICES](https://datras.ices.dk/Data_products/Download/Download_Data_public.aspx)) which are in an unusual format making it a challenge to efficiently import them to my R workspace.

The files are laid out like so:

```
V1 V2 V3 ... V60  
................  
................  
................  
V2.1 V2.2 V2.3 ... V2.27  
........................  
........................  
V3.1 V3.2 V3.3 ... V3.27  
........................  
........................
```

So, the issue is two-fold: there are three sets of (related) data stacked on top of one another in the csv file which I wish to be able to import as three separate objects in R; and these datasets have different dimensions and colnames.

So far, I have been using `count.fields()` on the files in the directory to identify the boundaries between each dataset, the `readLines()` to read the entire file as a character string for each row of data, then finally subsetting these chaacter strings acording to the values derived with `count.fields()`.

Are there any more direct methods? I feel like the approach I am currently using is quite inelegant. It should be noted that these are large csv files.

Comment: Can you actually fill the ellipsis with example data for a reproducible example?